# Java - How to access a file in root folder from test folder

Tags: java

I have a config file located in the root like this:

```
root
  config
    file.conf
  src
    main
      <main packages>
    test
      <test packages>
```

I'm accessing the file file.conf from a test inside a test package, but I can't seem to be able to access it using the standard class loader primitives. What's a right way to do this?

Comment: You need to add the `config` directory to classpath. How to do this depends on which tools you are using.

Comment: if you are using gradle use this..runtime files("${confDir}")
else simply add the folder in a classpath.

Comment: I added runtime files('config'), it's still not working. I'm using Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

To get the root path of your project:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

This will return the root folder of your project. From there, it should be a simple matter of drilling down to the resource you'd like to access.

Build tools and IDEs can make this more complicated than it should be though. Often, the resource returned is the resource that has been copied into the "out" or "build" directory of your project rather than the development version of the resource.

To avoid these issues you can opt to save the config file in the user's home directory, on Windows this would look something like:

c:\Users\userHome\

You can access the user's home directory like this:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

After you create your project home directory:

```
Path projPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\project Title\\");
Files.createDirectory(projPath);

Path configPath = Paths.get(projPath.toString() + "config.xml");
Files.createFile(configPath, REPLACE_IF_EXISTING);
```

You can load it:

```
Path configPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\\project title\\\config.xml"));
```

Then you can read the file from the path like normal.